# AWS Sagemaker Unable to read S3 data from certain regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have already uploaded my data to an AWS S3 bucket. I need to access the data in a Sagemaker notebook.

I made two notebook instances. One is in an "East" region while the other is "West". When I try to access the data in the "East" region it pulls up okay. But when I try to access the data from the "West" it give me an `NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.

How could one region work but the other fail on credentials?

In both cases this is the code I am using to access the data:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bucket='my-bucket'
role = get_execution_role()

data_key = 'my_data.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
df = pd.read_csv(data_location)
```

Comment: does your IAM role have policies scoped to a specific region?

Comment: @lauren, No it doesn't